# Jenkins doesn't run PM2

Tags: jenkins, pm2

I am trying to run PM2 using Jenkins Execute Shell as a last step of the build:

```
pm2 reload my-app
```

However, I am getting:

```
+ pm2 reload app-dev
/tmp/jenkins8632854138923533287.sh: 5: /tmp/jenkins8632854138923533287.sh: pm2: not found
```

Following steps has been done:

1. Node has been installed using `nvm`. Works fine.
2. `pm2` has been installed globally.
3. PM2 startup has been done successfully.
4. The folder `/home/me/.pm2` have permissions `me/users` and the user `jenkins` belongs to the `users` group.

What's missing there in order to execute `pm2` as a last step in the Jenkins build?

Comment: Could you execute just this  `node -v`  in Jenkins Execute Shell Build?

Comment: `node - v gives: v11.11.0`

However, If I use directly PM2 `/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/bin/pm2` then it works. I'd rather like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: Compare $PATH between s.o shell and jenkins shell

Comment: Indeed, `PATH` is different. However, I am able to execute PM2 by pointing directly to PM2, e.g. `/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/bin/pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --only my-app`. Unfortunately, this not good as I am getting `[PM2][WARN] Applications my-app not running, starting...` instead of `[PM2] Applying action reloadProcessId on app [my-app](ids: 0)`.

Which means to me that every time new completely process is starting.